# imgur api with curl not working php

Tags: php, api, curl

I've spent over an hour working on this and reading numerous tutorials.

imgur has an api that generate images like this
http://imgur.com/api/upload/?url=http://avatars.stocktwits.net/production/8483/thumb-1350729865.png

I am trying to get the outputted image in curl but can't get it to show anything.

```
<?php

$full = 'http://www.winningportfolio.com/images/styles/iBusiness/style/iconYoutube.png';

function get_image($url)  
{  
    $ch = curl_init();  
    $timeout = 5;  
    curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_URL,'http://imgur.com/api/upload/?url='.$url);  
    curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER,1);  
    curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_CONNECTTIMEOUT,$timeout);  
    $data = curl_exec($ch);  
    curl_close($ch);  
    return $data;  
}

//test it out!
$new_url = get_image($full);

echo $new_url;

?>
```

Comment: I'm guessing $full isn't properly URL encoded. (Shameless plug) You could run it through our tools to see what your code is generating on the way to the API.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should work :

```
function get_image($url)
{
    $ch = curl_init();
    curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_URL,'http://imgur.com/api/upload/?url=' . urlencode($url));
    curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_CONNECTTIMEOUT, 5);
    curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, true);
    curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
    curl_exec($ch);
    $lastUrl = curl_getinfo($ch, CURLINFO_EFFECTIVE_URL);
    curl_close($ch);
    return $lastUrl;
}

$full = 'http://www.winningportfolio.com/images/styles/iBusiness/style/iconYoutube.png';
var_dump( get_image($full) );
```

- `$url` should be urlencoded
- when you upload photos this way, redirects happend, so they must be followed
- if I understand your function returns new url? this can be done by `curl_getinfo()`

Comment: this works but how do I echo the result without the extra stuff? the result looks like: string(24) "http://imgur.com/otH7qPk"

Comment: What is extra stuff? `string(24)...` ? Use `echo` instead of `var_dump` ?

Comment: @GüntherHuber You could even do `echo "<img src='$full'>";` to show the image itself. Just saying.